# Get array object data from exploded array fields in foreach loop

Tags: arrays, php-7, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to extract data from our JSON data based on given output fields, but I'm not getting a good result.

e.g.

Given fields that I want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
    [2] => email
    [3] => optin_email
)
```

Those fields exist in my datastring, I want to export those to a CSV.

I can do this, hardcoded

```
foreach ($jsonString as $value) {

    $row = [
        $value->id,
        $value->name,
        $value->email,
        $value->phone
    ];

    print_r($row);
}
```

The above will give me the list/file I need. BUT, I want to make that dynamic based on the data in the array, so, fo rexample, when this is the Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
)
```

This should be my output:

```
foreach ($jsonString as $value) {

    $row = [
        $value->id,
        $value->name
    ];

    print_r($row);
}
```

So I need to dynamicly create the

```
$value->{var}
```

I have been trying forever, but I am not seeing it straight anymore.

Tried this:

```
$rowFields = '';       
foreach ($export_datafields AS $v) {
            $rowFields .= '$value->' . $v . ',';
        }
    $trimmed_row_fields = rtrim($rowFields, ',');

    foreach ($jsonString as $value) {

        $row = $trimmed_row_fields;
        print_r($row);
    }
```

And several variations of that:

```
foreach ($jsonString as $value) {

    $row = [$trimmed_row_fields];
    print_r($row);
}
```

Question is: how can I get

```
$value->VAR
```

as a valid array key when I only know the VAR name and need the prefixed $value-> object.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code which works for me. If anybody still has the answer to my original question, please shoot.  Always good to know it all.

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$csvFileName");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$new_row = implode(",", $export_datafields) . "\n";

foreach ($jsonString as $value) {
    foreach ($export_datafields AS $v) {
        $new_row .= $value->$v . ',';
    }
    $new_row = substr($new_row, 0, -1);

    $new_row .= "\n";
}
echo $new_row;
```